# How to remove a bitbucket account from a MAC

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have done something really dumb. I was in a hurry and since I needed to clone a project from my personal bitbucket account into my work laptop. So I did it using HTTPS and writing my password after the `git clone...`.

The problem is that I can now always `clone` (and `push`) all that I want from my personal repository without put my password and I have no idea how to change this.

Just in case "MAC" is not understandable, I am on OSX.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is all for windows credential manager...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you previously set:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

I think that's the default after `brew install git`. You can check with:

```
git config --list
```

Edit using KeyChain Access or at the command line:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

The GitHub documentation is nicer than Atlassian's in my opinion but the same things should apply.

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html

Comment: Yes! that was the case. Although using `git credential-osxkeychain erase` did nothing (it just hang there) that make me go into the *Keychain Access* app in my MAC and thee was my bitbucket account and I can delete it there.

Comment: @distante The problem was propably that you have to add the `host=bitbucket.org` and `protocol=https` in subsequent lines after running `git credential-osxkeychain erase`, and after that press ENTER twice, which is quite misleading in the referenced guide. @9bO3av5fw5 thanks for providing the resources on this.